# Deleting what unique_ptr points to

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, delete-operator

I have a coding assignment and I need to free whatever memory I allocate, so I'm trying to delete all the semaphores that my unique_ptr's are pointing to. The unique_ptrs are all in a map. The code snippets:

```
static map<string, unique_ptr<semaphore>> locks;
```

This is where all the semaphores are created using "new":

```
 89         unique_ptr<semaphore>& up = locks[article.title];
 90         if (up == nullptr) {
 91                 up.reset(new semaphore(6));
 92         }
```

Later, I try to delete the semaphores in the following code:

```
160         for (map<string, unique_ptr<semaphore>>::iterator it = locks.begin(); it != locks.end();
161                 ++it) {
162                 cout << it->first << endl;
163                 delete it->second;
164         }
```

And I get the compiler error:

```
news-aggregator.cc: In function âvoid processAllFeeds(const string&)â:
news-aggregator.cc:163:14: error: type âclass std::unique_ptr<semaphore>â argument given to âdeleteâ, expected pointer
make: *** [news-aggregator.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Just a side note, you might want to set your console to display UTF-8, so you don't get those `â`s everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do to delete what a `unique_ptr` points to is to [`reset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) the `unique_ptr`,

```
it->second.reset();
```

Comment: Or let it run out of scope, which might be the more common use case.

Answer (score 4):

The error is clear:

`delete` takes a `pointer` as argument, **not** a `unique_ptr`. **Why** you are trying to delete a pointer when you are using  `unique_ptr` for the very same purpose? The point of using *smart pointers* like `unique_prt` or `shared_ptr` is that they automatically delete the pointed object when no longer needed (i.e. out of scope) or you explicitly use `reset` .

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `std::unique_ptr` is to own a memory allocation and automatically `delete` it when it goes out of scope. IF you actually need to manually release the memory of a unique pointer early, there are ways to do it (`reset`, etc).

In your specific case, the memory will be automatically freed if you delete the entry in the container.

```
     for (auto it = locks.begin(), endit = locks.end(); it != endit; ++it) {
             cout << it->first << endl;
             delete it;
     }
```

Here we are deleting the element of the container, which implicitly calls the `unique_ptr`'s destructor, which `delete`s the memory it owns.

You can't use this pattern if container's iterators are invalidated by a delete.

If you have full C++11 support you could use:

```
    for (auto it : locks) {
        std::cout << it.first << '\n';
        delete it.second;
    }
```

But better still:

```
    for (auto it : locks)
        std::cout << it.first << '\n';
    locks.clear();
```

The call to `clear` will automatically call `unique_ptr::~unique_ptr` on the value of each element. If you don't have C++11, just replace the for loop with an iterator loop, the call to `clear` will have the same effect.